# How would I go about building node-chimera for windows?

Tags: c++, node.js, headless-browser

I have windows 7 and am interested in using node-chimera.

https://github.com/deanmao/node-chimera

They have no binaries for windows, how could I build this myself and install it into [NPM](https://npmjs.org/)?

I have visual studio 2012

(I tagged c++ because I think chimera is built in c++ but I have never compiled an c++ application)

Answer (score 0):

This is actually extremely non-trivial task to complile chimera on windows. For sure you've already got that chimera's developers use custom build of Qt framework (qt-project.org) in order to decrease the size of package. So if you are really intended to compile it you likely to repeat the actions performed for instance in the file - github.com/deanmao/node-chimera/blob/master/scripts/compile_qt.sh.

Previous step is the most painful IMHO. If you succeed it you'll be able to build other parts. Since chimera is native c++ addon to node.js so here (http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) you can find next build steps description, namely you'll have to download and install node.js binaries and finally build chimera sources using node-gyp tool that is distributed as part of node.js

This all description is quite nebulous, but I hope it'll give you some direction for further investigation)